# Paginate the uiwebview in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, epub, pagination

I'm now implementing an epub reader in iphone. I'm using uiwebview to display the files. It works fine but I cannot paginate a html file in uiwebview.
I use the following code to paginate the uiwebview:

```
for(id subviedw in myWebView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).pagingEnabled = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

It can paginate the uiwebview but it paginates vertically. How can I paginate the html file horizontally? (using javascript?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, it is possible to use CSS3 columns http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/ to break long text into pages on the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, I can paginate epub files now!!

Comment: hi @Oscar can u please provide a sample on how to  paginate html files on webview.i am struggling on this since a week.

Comment: FYI, these CSS properties worked well to the wrap the HTML page into columns. `-webkit-column-width: 300pt;-webkit-column-gap: 40pt;`

Comment: @Oscar Can you pls share the code that you have found . . .. . .